# itemBuilder function does not executing

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I use listView Builder to build ListView of categories from `Future<List<Category>>`, after debugging my code all things all right, except `itemBuilder` function not executing, when I debug `itemCount : snapshot.data.length` is executed but itemBuilder not executed, here is my code:

```
var categoryIcon = Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 0.0),
            child: Text(
              "Categories ",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 13.5,
                  fontFamily: "Sans",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: getCategories(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){

              if(snapshot.data == null){
                return Container(

                );
              }
              else{
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                      return new Container(
                          child: new Text(snapshot.data[index].name)););
                    },
                    itemCount : snapshot.data.length
                );
              }
            }
          ),
          /// Get class CategoryIconValue
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0))
        ],
      ),
    );
```

here is my **function for parsing Json** :

```
  Future<List<Category>> getCategories() async{
    var data = await http.get("http://192.168.0.134:9091/Categorie");
    var extractData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<Category> listCat = [];
    for(var c in extractData){
      Category cat = new Category(c["id"],c["name"]);
      listCat.add(cat);
    }
    print(listCat.length);
    return listCat;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new working with API in Flutter it will be good read about it, you can take a look at [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-apis-in-flutter-8745968103e9) written by Pooja and amazing post for exactly what you are doing, working with FutureBuilder.

Hope this help.